# How to compile C code on my website

Tags: c++, c

I want to link C compiler like GCC to my website which will gives the online errors and results.

How can I possibly do this?

Something like http://codepad.org/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Make a link in your website to http://codepad.org/ xD

Comment: Theodoros Chatzigiannakis No i have n't tried till now any thing first i should have some ideas related to that. Then only i can proceed.

Comment: Get the text - compile the code on the server - send back the results.

Comment: Or do you prefer to use a Continuous Integration (CI) server instead like Jenkins? Or perhaps use a CI server located elsewhere like Travis?

Answer (score 5):

You don't *link* the compiler to the website.
You just take the form input(code) and pass it to the compiler on your server and then display results it has returned.

Comment: +1. Simple and to the point.

Comment: It's possible to do it client side as well, though it would require a huge amount of work currently.

Comment: I can do this but this is too slow process .... like HTTP query. i want to embedded in my website.

Comment: I think not the speed but the security should be your most serious concerns. You have to make sure that users can't write viruses in your web form and let your server happily compile and execute it. I often wonder how other websites do this. I guess the executable should run in a very restrictive sandbox.

Comment: One thing they do is limit the amount of time given to the application during run-time. Some make the limit 3 seconds, some 5. (Still not quite enough security though)

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Well, that prevents you from DoS attacks, i.e. hackers can't kill your performance. But the biggest concern should be that hackers might try to compile some vulnerable code to execute shell commands, gain a shell login access (maybe even root), access the file system, or other intrusion tricks. A C compiler is the perfect opened door for such an attack. I mean, unless the program is executed in a really really well hardened sandbox environment (and even then).

Comment: Instant -1 for not even mentioning security.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath General answer for general question - He wanted an idea to work on and he got it.